# how to use conditional statement with multiple values within useEffect optimally

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, use-effect

I have multiple values that I want to use in `useEffect`.  The problem is that there is a conditional statement within that get executed according to the content of the values passed:

For example, let's say I have two values:

```js
const [value1, setValue1] = useState()
const [value2, setValue2] = useState()

useEffect(() => {
    if(value1 || value2) {
        // first logic
    } else {
        // second logic
    }
}, [value1, value2])
```

This won't work because `useEffect` runs every time either `value1` or `value2` updates.  The reason I don't want this is because if I want the "second logic" to run when `value1` is `false`, `value2` necessarily have to be `false`.

I can create separate `useEffect` for individual values, but the logic inside `useEffect` I currently have is super long and I have 7, 8 values I'm operating with so I'm looking to see if there are more optimal solutions out there.

Comment: The question is unclear to me. Can you please elaborate on: "`value2` necessarily have to be `false`."? Because using the OR operator, this is the behaviour you want, right?

Comment: I think this question relies on those "*7 or 8 values*" you have. The way you should handle this is 2 different `useEffect` with correct dependency arrays.

Comment: I agree with @MattOestreich. Then you can have value1 and value2 separately in the different dependency arrays.

Comment: To further elaborate, this is for React Native Switch toggle menu where each toggle does different execution.

Comment: Then you should def use 2 separate `useEffect`. It sounds like the issue is with your logic in those "*7 or 8 values*".

Comment: 7 or 8 values exist because there are 7 or 8 things to toggle in the menu. For example, there are 7 or 8 things a user wants to get notifications on.

Comment: something is not clear. if you want the second logic to run when the value1 is false, so you need to use && operator